# cv::Canny throws mismatched/unsupported formats exception

Tags: opencv, edge-detection

I'm doing some pretty basic edge detection stuff. Part of my implementation involves copying from a custom Image class to a cv::Mat and then copying back to an Image. I'm working with [this article](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/find_contours/find_contours.html) as my guide for getting the edge detection and contour work (not shown in the current listing) done. In this example, PerturbedBorderFilter subclasses Image. Here is what I have:

```
void PerturbedBorderFilter::performFilter(const Image& src)
{
  int h = src.Height(), w = src.Width();
  cv::Mat
    orig(h, w, CV_32FC3),
    cannyOutput(h,w,CV_32FC1),
    origGray(h,w,CV_32FC1);

  src.copyTo(orig);

  cv::cvtColor(orig, origGray, CV_RGB2GRAY);
  cv::blur(origGray, origGray, cv::Size(3,3));
  cv::Canny( origGray, cannyOutput, 0.1, 0.2, 3);

  copyFrom(cannyOutput);
}
```

I end up with this runtime error:

```
OpenCV Error: Unsupported format or combination of formats () in cvCanny, file /build/buildd/opencv-2.3.1/modules/imgproc/src/canny.cpp, line 67
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
  what():  /build/buildd/opencv-2.3.1/modules/imgproc/src/canny.cpp:67: error: (-210)  in function cvCanny
```

From what I can tell, 'origGray' and 'cannyOutput' share the same type, depth, and channel count. I am not sure what else I should check into.

If somehow the implementation of copyTo() and copyFrom() are important I can give those as well.

Some additional information:

1. Class Image's native color space is RGB, 32-bit float depth, with values in [0,1].
2. Currently, copyTo() copies the image upside down but intact otherwise. I figured this had to be unrelated, but who knows, maybe it is useful...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`cv::Canny` supports only `CV_8U` image depth.

Comment: Thanks! This was my problem... and yes it says so right in the documentation. oops.